# A question about bounds, least and minimal elements, and partial vs strict ordered sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It's not very clear to me if the concepts of **bounds**, **least elements** and **minimal elements** (also, greatest elements and maximal elements, etc. ) apply only to partial orders or if the definition applies to general ordered sets.

If I try to make an analogy between sets in general and the real numbers I would say that those definitions are explicitly made for partial orders, though I'm not sure and I don't know whether there are some sets with strict order to which the definitions apply.

For example, there is a theorem that says that "if $b$ is the least element of $B$ in some order on $A$ and $B\subseteq A$, then $b$ is the infimum of $B$". In this case I can think of the set $A=\{1,2,3\}$ with the usual strict order $<$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and $B=\{2,3\}$. Then $\inf(B)=1$ and $\min(B)=2$. But if I take the usual partial order $\leq$ then $\min(B)=\inf(B)=2$.

Here I'm using the next definition: Let $R$ be an ordering on $A$, and let $B\subseteq A$. Then,

1.- $a\in A$ is a lower bound of $B$ iff $\forall x\in B(a R x)$.

2.- $a\in B$ is a greatest element of $B$ iff $\forall x\in B(x R a)$.

3.- $a\in A$ is called an infimum of $B$ iff it is the greates element of the set of all lower bounds of $B$.

Note: For the example I'm assuming as proved that the greatest element an the infimum are unique.

**Edit:** Esentially what I'd like to know is to what kind of orders the definitions of bounds, least and greatest elements, minimal and maximal elements, etc. apply.

Comment: Your use of the phrase "partial order" is a bit confusing. I think you should use the terms "non-strict" vs. "strict", instead of "partial" vs. "strict". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders

Comment: As the above commenter points out your $\leq$ is actually a non-strict total order. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order  You should think of partial orders as Hasse diagrams or trees.  The $\leq$ on the reals is still a linear order and is not a good way to think of general partial orders.  Moreover, you can have strict partial orders usually denoted with $<$. So it is just irreflexive and transitive.  When we have a partial order it usually implies that there are elements that are not comparable i.e. we have $a \not\leq b$ and $b \not\leq a$.

Comment: Also, I don't think that $\inf(B)$ is ever equal to $1$ in your examples.  It should be $2$ regardless of whether you are thinking of $<$ or $\leq$.  I think you should explain more clearly what your exact question is and I think I could write up an answer.

Comment: @RyanSullivant Thanks for the comments. Maybe I'm wrong but using $<$ then $inf(B)$ cannot be $2$ because $(2,2)\notin <$ and the definition is that $\forall x\in B(inf(B)<x)$.

Comment: @Daniela Yes that is a bit confusing.  Its just because when ever we say greatest we mean we are using $\leq$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok these definitions are all for partial orders, but since total (linear) orders are partial orders as well, they work just as well for them.

Some things I will point out.  First, *bounds* are exactly like what they say there are.  There are bounds of the set in question (notices the s).  For example,

$A = \{1, 2, 3 \}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ and the order $<$, then $4, 5,$ and$ 1,000$ are all upper bounds, but the only lower bound is $0$.  But if instead we are thinking of $\leq$ then $3$ is also an upper bound and $1$ is also a lower bound.

Now, let $(A, \leq)$ be a partial ordered set and let $S \subset A$.

A *minimal* element of $S$ is an element $m$ such that there is no $n \in S$ such that $n \neq m $ and $n \leq m$.  Equivalently, for all $n \in S$ $n \leq m \implies n = m$. A *maximal* element of $S$ is an element $m$ such that there is no $n \in S$ such that $n \neq m$ and $m \leq n$.  Equivalently, for all $n \in S$ we have $m \leq n \implies m = n$ ([see here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Maximal_Element)).

A *least* element of $S$ is an element $l$ such that for all $s \in S$ we have $l \leq s$.  A *greatest* element of $S$ is an element $g$ such that for all $s \in S$ we have $s \leq g$.

I agree these two definitions (minimal/least and maximal/greatest) are a bit confusing as they are not equivalent, so let me give some examples.

So no take for example $A = \mathbb{N}$, $S = \{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12 \}$ and $\leq$ be the divides relation i.e. $a \leq b \text{ iff } a \mid b$ (this is a true partial order).  Then $2, 3, 5$ are all minimal elements and $10, 12$ are maximal elements. (This is why it is useful to look at the Hasse diagram, because you can pick out the minimal/maximal elements fairly quickly). But notice: $S$ has no least or greatest elements.  But now consider $S = \{3, 5, 15\}$.  Then again $S$ has $3, 5$ as minimal elements (and no least element), but $15$ is a maximal element and a greatest element.

Now, for infimum and supremum, you are looking at the greatest element of the *lower bounds* and the least element of the *upper bounds*.  So in you example, the set of lower bounds is $\{1, 2\}$ and so the greatest is $2$ (notice the definition of greatest includes equality see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_element)).

I can add more if you want and sorry if that explanation is a bit erratic.  Let me know what else you would like to know and I can expand this answer. Hope it helps a little!

Comment: Also, I would just like to say, if you are working with general partial orders you will definitely use minimal and maximal elements much more than least or greatest.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for the excellent explanation. Now I feel kind of stupid for the question but I was really confused because I thought the definitions applied to orders in general. Now I know by Asaf's answers that the definitions indeed might apply to any order, but as you say in this cases the definitions clearly apply to partial orders (I finally noticed this because they use the symbol $leq$ instead of $<$ or $R$ in case of talking about general orders).

Comment: @Daniela I'm glad it helped.  I just edited my answer on the definition of minimal/maximal (I needed to make sure the $n$ I was comparing it to was distinct from $m$ otherwise my statement was false).  I think it may be a little clearer now.  And yes, partial order is usually the standard place to define these things. Linear orders are just partial orders with nicer properties.

Comment: a comment on uniqueness would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when we say "ordered sets" we usually mean that the set is partially ordered, and often even more (i.e. totally ordered, and in some contexts even well-ordered).

Secondly, $1\neq\inf\{2,3\}$. In the real numbers if $A$ has a minimum, then $\min A=\inf A$. In fact, it is easy to see that if $\min A$ exists then $\inf A=\min A$, whenever the two notions are defined.

Why? Well, what is $\inf A$? It is some $x$ such that for all $a\in A$ we have $x\leq a$, and whenever $y$ is such that $y\leq a$ (for all $a\in A$, of course) then we have $y\leq x$. But if $m=\min A$ exists then it is a member of $A$, so whenever $x$ is such that $x\leq a$ for all $a\in A$, in particular $x\leq m$.

If you want to prove the uniqueness of $\inf$, and $\inf$ is defined as the greatest element of lower bounds, then proving the uniqueness of "greatest element" would suffice.

And how do you prove uniqueness? Suppose that $x$ and $y$ are greatest element of $B$, and show that by definition we have to have $x=y$. **Hint:** You have to use antisymmetry here.

Comment: In your definition of $inf(A)$ you're applying the $\leq$ relation, meaning your definition applies to partially ordered sets, in this case a linear order,  so my question is just right there that if these sort of definitions apply always to partial ordered sets or to any other sort of orders, like strict orders, using the $<$ relation, or any order in general. Maybe my question is a little bit clearer if for example the set $A=\{1,2,3\}$ is ordered by the $|$ relation (divisibility in number theory) and we try to apply these definitions of bounds, least element, etc.

Comment: @Daniela: Yes, $\inf$ and $\min$ are easily definable for every partial order. But being definable doesn't mean you exist. Note that $\sqrt2$ is easily definable in the language fields, but that doesn't mean $\sqrt2$ exists in every field.

Comment: @Daniela also check my answer.  Greatest is defined as an element that is *greater than or equal to* every other element in your set (see the wiki link).

Comment: @RyanSullivant Ok. Thanks I'm just processing the information.I'll add some details or comments if necessary.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry for my silly questions, maybe you're laughing at me but I was really confused. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Daniela: I don't laugh at people who try to understand mathematics. And if I do, it's most definitely not because of that.